Spring Security 6.2.0 OAuth2 configuration via XML
I am working with a legacy Spring application which uses XML configuration.
A new requirement is to introduce the OAuth2 client-credentials flow for a couple of specific webhook endpoints. I am currently using Spring Security 6.2.0.
All of the documentation I have found on configuring OAuth 2 for Spring Security 6.2.0 gives examples using Java based configuration.
Does anyone know where I can get documentation on how to configure the Spring OAuth2 Authorization and Resource servers using XML configuration using Spring 6.2.0?
I have been unable to find documentation on how to configure Spring 6.2.0 OAuth2 Authorization and Resource servers using XML configuration.
